# How to rotate ImageButton source Image with Animation.

Tags: android, android-xml, image-rotation

I need to rotate the drawable resource of ImageButton. I've succeeded rotating functionality to my Button but rotating functionality affect whole button. All I want to do is rotate only drawable inside ImageButton.

[image]

How to handle this situation ? 
PS: I accessed drawable inside ImageButton but I wasn't able give any animation functionality.

Thanks in helpings

Here my ImageButton xml;

```
 <ImageButton
   android:id="@+id/button"
   android:layout_width="50dp"
   android:layout_height="50dp"
   android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
   android:layout_marginTop="-40dp"
   android:background="@color/titlebackground_color"
   android:src="@drawable/open" />
```

Rotate first xml;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="-180"
        android:toDegrees="-360"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="500"
        android:startOffset="0"
        />
</set>
```

Rotate Second xml;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="-180"
        android:toDegrees="-0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="500"
        android:startOffset="0"

        />
</set>
```

Animation functionality;

```
public class LayerInfoFragment extends Fragment {
 int count = 0;
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layer_info_main, container, false);
        btnClose = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.button);
        btnClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Animation rotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.rotate_first);
                Animation rotatex = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.rotate_last);

                if (count % 2 == 0) {
                    v.setRotation(180);
                    v.setAnimation(rotate);


                } else {
                     v.setRotation(0);
                     v.setAnimation(rotatex);
                }
                count++;


            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you rotate the image in java before giving it to the imageButton?

Comment: I dont understand well. My aim is when first click the button rotate image 180 degree and second click image turn first position.

Comment: I have not used Animation, have used ObjectAnimator. I read Animation class a bit and read related posts quickly. I will post an answer to start.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things to try I think.

1)  Add code `v.startAnimation(rotate);` after `v.setAnimation()`. I suspect your animation never got started. I was thinking before that android:startOffset in the settings would trigger a start but that is not clear to me.

2) Try **RotateAnimation**, a direct subclass of Animation, instead of Animation objects. It seems many used RotateAnimation more than anything else.  Besides that, the other issue I suspect is in the layout file.
Example:

```
RotateAnimation rotate = (RotateAnimation) AnimationUtils.loadAnimation...
```

Tell us what happens.